# Plot the stacked bar graph in MATLAB with original values instead of a cumulative summation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

By original values, I mean that when I create the stacked bar graph, MATLAB automatically appends values to its previous ones to create a cumulative summation. This is illustrated by taking an example from MATLAB official site, whose screenshot is shown below

[image]
Here first the value `2` is plotted, then `2+2` and then `2+2+3`. What if we have to plot the values as they are, which means plotting  `[2 2 3]` instead of `[2 4 7]`. Also, I want to plot the values given in variable `y` as a stacked bar graph in above screenshot as if those are real values.

Help, please!

Comment: It's easy to undo a cumulative sum, for example plot `[y(:,1) diff(y)]`

Comment: Plotting `bar([y(:,1) diff(y)],'stacked')` did not produced any result. Did you mean doing it in some other way?

Comment: Just plot them as separate series... i.e. individually in a loop

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be `bar([y(:,1) diff(y,1,2)], 'stacked')` to do the differencing along rows instead of columns.  Is that good enough for you or do you need a "better" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a 3D graph and then change the view angle.

```
y=[2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];
bar3(y)
view(-90,0)
```

The above code was used to generate this graph.
[image]

Comment: Nice and easy answer